# Populate dynamodb table with default values in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I'm working on a **CDK** project in which I need to populate dynamodb table that I'm creating with CDK with some default items. How can I achieve this using AWS-CDK? If not is there any option to run a secondary script once the dynamodb table is created.

Answer (score 6):

There you go, an example on how to use Custom Resource to populate a DynamoDB table:

```
import * as cr from '@aws-cdk/custom-resources';

const dynamoDb = new Table(this, 'UserDatabase', {
  partitionKey: { name: 'Name', type: AttributeType.STRING, },
  pointInTimeRecovery: true,
  billingMode: BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
  timeToLiveAttribute: 'ttl'
});

new cr.AwsCustomResource(this, 'initTable', {
      onCreate: {
        service: 'DynamoDB',
        action: 'putItem',
        parameters: {
            TableName: dynamoDb.tableName,
            Item: { Name: { S: "User1" } }
        },
        physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(dynamoDb.tableName + '_initialization')
      },
      policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({ resources: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE }),
    });
```

The following article helped me to get it working: https://dev.to/elthrasher/exploring-aws-cdk-loading-dynamodb-with-custom-resources-jlf

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Custom Resource for that. It allows you to run any AWS SDK commands you want on trigger.

Comment: Do you have a sample code that I can test it out?

Answer (score 0):

python example:

```
      for i, item in enumerate(items):
        put_item = AwsSdkCall(
            action='putItem',
            service='DynamoDB',
            parameters={
                "TableName": credit_details_table.table_name,
                "Item": item
            },
            physical_resource_id=PhysicalResourceId.of(f'PutItem{i}')
        )

        AwsCustomResource(self,
                            f'PutItem{i}',
                            on_create=put_item,
                            policy=AwsCustomResourcePolicy.from_sdk_calls(resources=[credit_details_table.table_arn]))
```